# Aggregation : $match MongoDB documents that have an $avg value greater than something

Tags: mongodb, average, aggregation

I'm trying to understand Aggregation in MongoDB and wanted to do a simple query with a single `$match` stage that selects documents where the score average is greater than 80.

I need this to be in an **aggregate** (not a **find**) because I want after the $match to do other things ($group). So a `.find()` with `$exp` operator won't help me.

Here's my "grades" collection :

```js
// Collection "grades" :
[
    { _id: 1, name: 'Susan Wilkes', scores: [ 87, 86, 78 ] },
    { _id: 2, name: 'Bob Hanna', scores: [ 71, 64, 81 ] },
    { _id: 3, name: 'James Torrelio', scores: [ 91, 84, 97 ] }
]
```

I've tried with this, but it doesn't gives any output in the console.

```js
db.grades.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            scores: { $gt: [{ $avg: "$scores" }, 80] }
        },
    },

    // { $group: … }
])
```

Maybe it's a matter of syntax or order in operators, but I can't figure what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but your example (and the duplicate) show a solution with `.find()`, whereas I need to do this in an aggregate pipeline. In fact, I want to first $match only documents that has a sufficient average to perform others operations after.

Comment: It's the same query really `db.grades.aggregate([{$match:{$expr:{$gt:[{$avg:'$scores'},80]}}}])`

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#restrictions

Comment: Ofh! Sorry then, I mixed several things in my minds. I tried to replace the $match with $exp (which obviously doesn't works). Makes sense now. Thank you :) Solved!